# Convert object(int[,]} to int[,]

Tags: c#, object, casting, type-conversion, ascom

I'm trying to write simple program to get image from astronomy camera, image data is read as object{int[,]} according to this doc: 
[ASCOM.DriverAccess.Camera.ImageArray](https://ascom-standards.org/Help/Developer/html/P_ASCOM_DriverAccess_Camera_ImageArray.htm)

To display and convert this data to image I want to convert it to 2D int array. Could someone help me how to do this? Or maybe it's better, simpler way to convert this image object array to image...

Comment: You are trying to write a program, do you have any code to share?

Answer (score 0):

What you seemingly have is a `SafeArray`.

> The application must inspect the Safearray parameters to determine the
>   dimensions.

You may be able to do this

```
Array ct = (Array)SomeFunkyArrayTypeYouGet;
int[,] content = new int[ct.GetUpperBound(0), ct.GetUpperBound(1)];
ct.CopyTo(content, 0);
```

<sub>**Note** : I have not tested this, nor confident it will work, it's based on a [result I found with a quick web search](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Aug/26/Accessing-a-SafeArray-Result-from-a-COM-Call-in-C)</sub>

Comment: Ok, now I understand how works this SafeArray. Your example works fine, except CopyTo(), beacuse it work only with one dimensional arrays. I used instead Clone().